# Microsoft Edge for .NET Load tests

Tags: .net, microsoft-edge, load-testing, visual-studio-loadtest

I've been trying to run load test on one of my .NET applications.

Is it possible to add "Microsoft Edge" as a browser mix? As of now, I can only see different versions of IE AND Chrome/firefox available in the drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add Edge to Browser list in `Browser configuration` section, something like this:

[image]